# AngularJS convert Date to getTime() before sending to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have a form that uses `<input type="datetime-local" ng-bind="course.endDate"..` and sets a variable of the model.
Before sending the date to the server I've to convert the date `2015-04-04T22:00:00.000Z` to a `integer` given by the `getTime()`.

In the controller i added this: `course.endDate = course.endDate.getTime();` it works for the server side but angular complains in the console with [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=1325458800000).  (*as said, it works, but I would like to avoid errors*)

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `1325458800000` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngModel/datefmt?p0=1325458800000
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:19938)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (angular.js:23419)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14300)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
    at done (angular.js:9698)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9888)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9829)
```

How can i do then?

I had the idea of adding some fields that are used in the form (`formEndDate`) and convert to another one (`endDate = formEndDate.getTime()`) for the server side, but in this way the server refuse the call since the parameter `formEndDate` is not allowed, and if I remove the `formEndDate` then everything breaks.

**additional problem:**
When i fetch data from the server I have an integer that needs to be converted into a date to be used in the form. so I've to convert the date also before allowing an edit. how can I do this? (the data fetched are into an array, so would be terrific to have the conversion without having to iterate on the whole array)

### solution

thanks to the two answers (I set correct the first that came) I also (somehow) solved the problem of the form when editing. I did so by creating an extra field and use it for the form when editing (I do inline editing).

I created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/esseti/fcb3d5257ef6df812f01)

Comment: it was linked, i added it. BTW when i fetch data from the server I have an integer that needs to be converted into a `date` to be used in the form. so I've to convert the date also before allowing an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before sending the data to the server, make a copy and set `endDate`. Then send the copy to the server:

```
var courseCopy = angular.copy(course);
courseCopy.endDate = courseCopy.endDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i've the problem when i fetch the data. see the updated question.

Comment: Why is iterating the array an issue?

Comment: because I may have to do it in many places. And i would like to avoid it.

Comment: Depending on your application, another option might be to also copy the data just before going to the edit page. This would also avoid messing with scope data.

Comment: Since this was the first answer I mark it as correct. *for the form problem i solved with a trick. I'll update the question*

Answer (score 2):

In angular it's good to keep all form data under one property, like:

```
$scope.formData = {endDate : 'xxx', ...};
```

Before sending data to server, you need to create a copy of `formData`:

```
  var formDataCopy= angular.copy($scope.formData);
```

Then you can make any transfomation operations on given copy. Any changs will not affect data in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `transformRequest` to transform the request's body, like so (taken from the [official docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http):

```
function appendTransform(defaults, transform) {
  // We can't guarantee that the default transformation is an array
  defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? defaults : [defaults];

  // Append the new transformation to the defaults
  return defaults.concat(transform);
}

$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformRequest: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformRequest, function(value) {
    // transform the payload here
    return value;
  }),
  transformResponse: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse, function(value) {
    // transform the response here
    return value;
  })
});
```